# Using Sixlabour.ImageSharper on ASP.NET Core mvc on Product Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my project product page controller, I want to upload a image and after submit the image automatically compress so I use `Sixlabour.ImageSharper`. It's working in my demo project (where I only add one input field image). When I shifted this code in my main project it's not working.

This is my code:

**ProductController.cs**

```
public string ResizeImage(Image img, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
        if (img.Width > maxWidth || img.Height > maxHeight)
        {
            double widthRatio = (double)img.Width / (double)maxWidth;
            double heightRatio = (double)img.Height / (double)maxHeight;
            double ratio = Math.Max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
            int newWidth = (int)(img.Width / ratio);
            int newHeight = (int)(img.Height / ratio);
            return newHeight.ToString() + "," + newWidth.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return img.Height.ToString() + "," + img.Width.ToString();
        }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upsert(ProductVM productVM,IFormFile file)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string webRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

            if (files.Count > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                var uploads = Path.Combine(webRootPath, @"images\products");
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);
                
                using (var image = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream()))
                {
                    string newSize = ResizeImage(image, 500, 500);
                    string[] aSize = newSize.Split(',');
                    image.Mutate(h => h.Resize(Convert.ToInt32(aSize[1]), Convert.ToInt32(aSize[0])));
                }
                
                if (productVM.Product.ImageUrl != null)
                {
                    //this is an edit and we need to remove old image
                    var imagePath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, productVM.Product.ImageUrl.TrimStart('\\'));

                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagePath))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(imagePath);
                    }
                }

                using(var filesStreams = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, fileName + extension), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    files[0].CopyTo(filesStreams);
                }

                productVM.Product.ImageUrl = @"\images\products\" + fileName + extension;
            }
            else
            {
                //update when they do not change the image
                if(productVM.Product.Id != 0)
                {
                    Product objFromDb = _unitOfWork.Product.Get(productVM.Product.Id);
                    productVM.Product.ImageUrl = objFromDb.ImageUrl;
                }
            }


            if (productVM.Product.Id == 0)
            {
                _unitOfWork.Product.Add(productVM.Product);

            }
            else
            {
                _unitOfWork.Product.Update(productVM.Product);
            }
            _unitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        
        return View(productVM);
    }
```

```
I used webrootpath for uploading images.how can I solve this
**Error** show "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on using (var image = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream()))
```

Comment: anyone any solution?

Comment: Hi @Soumik Mahajan, This error message means the `file` does not have value. Did you set breakpoint and check if IFormFile file receives value? Please share how do you post the value, by postman or by razor view form? If post by razor view form please share more code.

Comment: yeah I solved it thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by own
here is the solution..I remove webRoot path, and call it manually

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upsert(ProductVM productVM, IFormFile file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
                if (files.Count > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = string.Empty;
                    string path = string.Empty;
                    if (file.Length > 0) //that means file was uploaded
                    {
                        fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        path = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/images/products"));
                        string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
                        using (var image = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream()))
                        {
                            string newSize = ResizeImage(image, 500, 500);
                            string[] aSize = newSize.Split(',');
                            image.Mutate(h => h.Resize(Convert.ToInt32(aSize[1]), Convert.ToInt32(aSize[0])));
                            image.Save(fullPath);
                        }

                        if(productVM.Product.Id != 0 )
                        {
                            Product objFromDb = await _unitOfWork.Product.GetAsync(productVM.Product.Id);
                            productVM.Product.ImageUrl = objFromDb.ImageUrl;

                            if(objFromDb.ImageUrl!= null)
                            {
                                //Image already exists we need to remove old image
                                var imagepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), objFromDb.ImageUrl.TrimStart('\\'));
                                if (System.IO.File.Exists(imagepath))
                                    System.IO.File.Delete(imagepath);
                            }
                        }

                        productVM.Product.ImageUrl = @"\images\products\" + fileName;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //update when they do not change the image
                    if (productVM.Product.Id != 0)
                    {
                        Product objFromDb = await _unitOfWork.Product.GetAsync(productVM.Product.Id);
                        productVM.Product.ImageUrl = objFromDb.ImageUrl;
                    }
                }


                if (productVM.Product.Id == 0)
                {
                   await _unitOfWork.Product.AddAsync(productVM.Product);

                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfWork.Product.Update(productVM.Product);
                }
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            
            
            }
            return View(productVM);
        }

        public string ResizeImage(Image img, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
        {
            if (img.Width > maxWidth || img.Height > maxHeight)
            {
                double widthRatio = (double)img.Width / (double)maxWidth;
                double heightRatio = (double)img.Height / (double)maxHeight;
                double ratio = Math.Max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
                int newWidth = (int)(img.Width / ratio);
                int newHeight = (int)(img.Height / ratio);
                return newHeight.ToString() + "," + newWidth.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return img.Height.ToString() + "," + img.Width.ToString();
            }
        }
```